# Spliting a list into sizes specified by another list

Tags: python, list, iterator, slice

Let say there's a list X and another list `num_items` that specify the number of items that should be in the sublist, I can split the list manually as such:

```
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> num_items = [4, 4, 2]

>>> slice1 = x[:num_items[0]]
>>> slice2 = x[len(slice1):len(slice1)+num_items[1]]
>>> slice3 = x[len(slice1)+len(slice2):]
>>> slice1, slice2, slice3
([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9])
```

There will be two cases where the last few slices can become problematic, e.g. but that can be solved with the empty list given that I manually code the 3 slices:

```
>>> num_items = [9, 1, 1]
>>> slice1 = x[:num_items[0]]
>>> slice2 = x[len(slice1):len(slice1)+num_items[1]]
>>> slice3 = x[len(slice1)+len(slice2):]
>>> slice1, slice2, slice3
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9], [])
```

What if there are 4 slices, e.g.:

```
>>> num_items = [9, 1, 1, 2]
>>> slice1 = x[:num_items[0]]
>>> slice2 = x[len(slice1):len(slice1)+num_items[1]]
>>> slice3 = x[len(slice1)+len(slice2):len(slice1)+len(slice2)+num_items[2]]
>>> slice4 = x[len(slice1)+len(slice2)+len(slice3): len(slice)+len(slice2)+len(slice3)+num_items[3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

The desired output would be to add empty list to the 4th slice, i.e.:

```
>>> slice1, slice2, slice3, slice4
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9], [], [])
```

If the `num_items` requires lesser items than length of X, simply return until the sum of `num_items`, i.e.

```
>>> num_items = [4, 4]
>>> slice1, slice2
([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7])
```

**The main question is is there a way to split up the slices without manually coding the splits?** (The answer to cover the case where the `num_items` requests for more items than in X, in that case, empty sublists should be returned)

Keep in mind that the length of X can be rather big (i.e. > 10,000,000,000) but the length of `num_items` ranges from 1 to 100 =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a different approach:

```
[[x.pop(0) for _ in x[:s]] for s in num_items]
```

**Examples:**

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> n = [9, 1, 1]
>>> [[x.pop(0) for y in x[:s]] for s in n]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9], []]

>>> x = range(10)
>>> n = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> [[x.pop(0) for y in x[:s]] for s in n]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], []]

>>> x = range(10)
>>> n = [3, 4, 5, 2]
>>> [[x.pop(0) for y in x[:s]] for s in n]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], []] # Notice here how slice 5 only returns 3 numbers because there are only 3 numbers left in x
```

Comment: Kind of scary but compared to your approach, manually declaring the slices saves 0.5 secs for each run on average across 1000 runs =)

Answer (score 4):

Crude but simple way of doing that.

```
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> num_items = [2,3,4,1]
>>> cur_sum = 0
>>> slices = []
>>> for i in num_items:
...     slices.append(x[cur_sum:cur_sum+i])
...     cur_sum += i
... 
>>> slices
[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind, but somehow thought of some other case. Confusion. Thanks! Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> num_items = [9, 1, 1]
>>> s = 0
>>> for i in num_items:
...     print x[s:s + i]
...     s += i
...
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[9]
[]
```