# Combining multiple lists of different lengths in a lists of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list of lists like:

```
list1=[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

I have to combine lists of lengths given by another list like:

```
list2=[1, 2, 3]
```

> The final result should be like this:  [ [1], [2,3], [4,5,6] ].

How can I proceed to do this?I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42693268/2148023

Comment: What if one of the lists in the original `list1` contains two or more items. Or is an empty list?

Comment: In my case, lists in list1 always have one element and are never empty

Comment: @CarlesMitjans That question is similar, but list1 in that case is a list, not a list of lists

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an iterator on `list1` in a list comprehension over `list2`:

```
>>> list1=[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
>>> list2=[1, 2, 3]
>>> v = iter(list1)
>>> [sum((next(v) for _ in range(a)), []) for a in list2]
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

`v` is an iterator over `list1`; `next(v)` simply returns the next sublist in the list. In the comprehension, `a` takes on the values in `list2`, which denote the lengths of the combined lists we want. The `sum(...)` is what actually takes `a` sublists (via `range(a)`) from `list1` (via `next(v)`) and combines them into a single list.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. A little explanation about the code would be helpful.